# Is there a way to install Node.js without admin rights on a mac?

Tags: macos, installation, node.js

I'm trying to use Node.js on my work computer but I don't have admin rights. My company is pretty strict on what we can install, even if I explain why I need it. So, I'm wondering if it is possible install Node.js on mac without having admin rights?

Comment: @dandavis okay, how would I do that?

Comment: nevermind, i'm not sure my experience applies to you.

Comment: I found this tutorial but I'm stuck at the "Configure the PATH" part: 
https://theshravan.net/blog/how-to-use-node-and-npm-without-installation-or-admin-rights/

Comment: that looks like windows instructions, which is what i was thinking of originally. you might just get a cheap or free VPS that you can use from anywhere for anything you want, or maybe a virtual PC that gives you rights.